# Ansible library strategy?

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm starting to use ansible for configuration management and wondering how to structure my ansible directory. For instance, `web1` is a host which needs configuration edits made to *Apache* and */etc/ssh/sshd_config*. `jira1` is a host which doesn't use *Apache*, but does need the same edits made to */etc/ssh/sshd_config*.

My thought was to make a library directory under my `ansible` directory and put a `sshd.yml` under the playbooks. I could make host directory with symlinks to the library:

```
ansible
   |
   |
   + library
   |       |
   |       +- sshd.yml
   |       +- apache.yml
   |       +- nginx.yml
   + web1
   |    |  
   |    + playbooks
   |              |
   |              +- symlink_to_../../library/sshd.yml
   |              +- symlink_to_../../library/apache.yml
   + jira1
        |  
        + playbooks
                  |
                  +- symlink_to_../../library/sshd.yml
                  +- symlink_to_../../library/nginx.yml
```

This eliminates duplicate `.yml` files and ansible doesn't seem to mind the symlinks. At a glance into a subdirectory I can tell exactly which playbooks are needed/used for configuring a given host. It seems like a good scheme but is there a better way of doing this?

The only other thing I can think of is outfit every playbook with `vars/facts` which include/exclude every single host from configuration. That seems like the long way around though; edting every single playbook any time I add or remove a host from the LAN.

Comment: Are you aware of [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html) concept?

Comment: Somewhat. I have a basic inventory setup with 70 hosts under an '[all]' group. I watched a couple 'ansible basics' webinars that didn't really get into large scale deployments. Clearly I need to do more research. thanks.

Comment: `sshd`, `apache` and `nginx` seems to be good candidates for `roles` and `web` and `jira` – for `groups` in your inventory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Konstantin wrote, you should have roles for those standard building blocks, groups per server type and playbooks to apply those roles. So your structure would be something like this:

```
ansible
   |
   |
   +-roles
   |   |
   |   +-sshd
   |   +-apache
   |   +-nginx
   |
   +-playbook_for_group_web.yml
   |
   +-playbook_for_group_jira.yml
```

Comment: Starting to make more sense now. I wasn't clear how roles were used. Thanks for the additional clarification.